# Tracking the external website which generated a Facebook Like

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We have various properties across the internet, which each have "Like" buttons for the same Facebook sites. We want to be able to track which sites (which domain) generated the Like.

We are using the XMLFB Facebook Like button implementation, and also filled out the `data-ref` parameter with the site (although from what I've read the `data-ref` is just used to track like clicks from a Facebook profile after a Like occurs). Our goal is to attribute each Like to each specific Like button or domain in which the Like occured.

Here is what I tried:

- Setting up insights on the Facebook site which the Like was generated for. There are no explicit sources by domain or data-ref.
- Setting up insights on the Facebook site which generated the like (insights for websites). I found the insights was not logging the Likes correctly.
- I looked into the FQL and the closest thing i got to metrics on detailed like source data was the `page_fans_by_like_source` but that turned out to be irrelevant.

Does anyone have any insights as to how I can achieve my desired functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ref parameter on likes doesn't work](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12198556/ref-parameter-on-likes-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to track this is to do this yourself, by subscribing to the 'edge.create' events published by the JS SDK on the individual sites.

Comment: Sean, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I appreciate it.